# Angularfire 7.5 queries, why I get undefined?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm working on a project with Angularfire 7.5, Angular 15.
I'm having difficulties understanding how Angularfire queries returns results.

I have a a "settings" collection with a document (ID: "settings") that has one reference field:
[image: Settings]

I'm trying to get the data from the document referenced in the collection "settings", so in my service I have this method:

```
getCurrentGroup(): void {
   this.firestore.collection<Settings>(this.collectionName).doc<Settings>('settings').valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => {
       data?.currentGroup.get().then(res => { console.log(res.data()) });
   });
}
```

Where from the collection "settings" I get the document reference then use the get() method to get its data, this is working fine, I get in the console the correct data.
But since I want to have the data in a component and not in the service, I change my service method to:

```
getCurrentGroup(): any {
    this.firestore.collection<Settings>(this.collectionName).doc<Settings>('settings').valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => {
      if (data !== undefined) return data?.currentGroup.get();
      else return undefined;
    });
  }
```

Then in my component I use then() function to get the promise's result:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.settingsService.getCurrentGroup().then(data => console.log(data));
 }
```

But the result is: method getCurrentGroup() is undefined.

What can I do to solve this issue?

I know that probably there is A LOT wrong on how I'm writing this code but I'm a complete newbie on Angular and Firebase and I'm trying to understand how they work together and how Observable / Promises works.

Comment: `getCurrentGroup` returns nothing

Comment: `getCurrentGroup` performs a subscription but it dosn't return anything to the caller.

Comment: You cannot paste pictures as code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask